# Serialize response object with generic nested data object with GSON

Tags: json, generics, nested, gson, realm

I am using Retrofit with GSON for JSON serialization and Realm for storage.

My JSON Responses always look like (simplyfied)

```
{
   status : 1
   data: { object data }
}
```

So I have meta information and a data root object which contains the result (object or array)

Now I am trying to write a custom deserializer for GSON which converts the result to a object or list of objects.

For me it only works with static object type definitions like:

```
public class ResponseDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer {

@Override
public Object1 deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
{
    JsonElement data = je.getAsJsonObject().get("data");
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    Object1 o1 = gson.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<Object1>() {}.getType());
    return o1;
}
}
```

First question: When I try to change to a generic type fromJson results in an "com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap" with key value pairs of the object, code:

```
public class ResponseDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

@Override
public T deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
{
    JsonElement data = je.getAsJsonObject().get("data");
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    T o = gson.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<T>() {}.getType());
    return o;
}
}
```

Second question: How can the deserializer return an object or a list of objects depending on the json result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I have solved it with an different approach:

2 response models for list and object:

```
public class ApiResponse<T> {
    private int success;
    private String[] errors;
    private String[] messages;
    private T data;
}

public class ApiListResponse<T> {
    private int success;
    private String[] errors;
    private String[] messages;
    private List<T> data;
}
```

1 deserializer for the response models

```
public class ResponseDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer {
@Override
public T deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonElement data = je.getAsJsonObject().get("data");
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    T response = gson.fromJson(je, type);
    return response;
}
}
```

And now i can register types for GSON like:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<ApiResponse<Object1>>() {}.getType(), new ResponseDeserializer<ApiResponse>());
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<ApiListResponse<Object1>>() {}.getType(), new ResponseDeserializer<ApiListResponse>());
```

And now the following JSON responses will be converted correctly:

ApiResponse

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "Object1Id":"1",
      "Name":"Test 1",
   },
   "messages":[  
   ],
   "errors":[  
   ],
   "success":"1"
}
```

ApiListResponse

```
{  
   "data":[{  
      "Object1Id":"1",
      "Name":"Test 1",
   },{  
      "Object1Id":"2",
      "Name":"Test 2",
   }],
   "messages":[  
   ],
   "errors":[  
   ],
   "success":"1"
}
```

Are there better solutions?